# Erro de acesso ajax com url amigavel

Tags: php, ajax

Ola pessoal eu tenho um problema meu sistema esta com url amigável estou fazendo uma atualização pelo ajax, mas quando vou testar para obter os dados da erro de pagina não encontrada 404 segue os codigos fontes.

Viwer.js

```
$(function() {
    form = $('form[name="atualizar"]');
    action = 'swith/controler.php';

    form.submit(function(){
        var atualizar = $('input[name="enviar"]').val();

        $.post('swith/controler.php',{enviar: atualizar},function(valores){
            alert(valores);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

viwer.php

```
<div class="teste">
                  <form name="atualizar" id="test" action="" method="POST">
                      <input type="submit" class='btn btn-green contar' name="enviar" value="contar viwer">
                  </form>

              </div>
```

config.inc.php - responsável pelo sistema

```
<?php


// Configuração de hora do servidor
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");


define('HOME', 'http://localhost/tamplet');
define('THEME', 'speedviwer');

define ('INCLUDE_PATH', HOME . '/themes/' . THEME);
define ('REQUIRE_PATH', 'themes/' . THEME);

###### CONFIGURAÇÕES DO SITE ###########
define ('HOST','localhost');
define ('USER','root');
define ('PASS','');
define ('DBSA','tamplet');



// AUTO LOAD DE CLASSES ###########
function __autoload($Class) {

    $cDir = ['conn', 'helpers', 'models'];
    $iDir = null;

    foreach($cDir as $dirNmae):
        if(!$iDir && file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$dirNmae}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$Class}.class.php") && !is_dir(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$dirNmae}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$Class}.class.php")):
        include_once (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$dirNmae}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$Class}.class.php");
        $iDir = true;
    endif;
    endforeach;

    if(!$iDir):
        trigger_error("Não foi possível incluir {$Class}.class.php", E_USER_ERROR);
        die;
    endif;
    }




    // TRATAMENTO DE ERROS ############
    //CSS constantes :: Mensagens de Erro

    define('WS_ACCEPT','accept');
    define('WS_INFOR','infor');
    define('WS_ALERT','alert');
    define('WS_ERROR','error');

    //WSErro :: Exibe erros lançados :: Front
    function WSErro($ErrMsg, $ErrNo, $ErrDie = null){
        $CssClass = ($ErrNo == E_USER_NOTICE ? WS_INFOR : ($ErrNo == E_USER_WARNING ? WS_ALERT : ($ErrNo == E_USER_ERROR ? WS_ERROR : $ErrNo)));
        echo "<p class=\"trigger {$CssClass}\">{$ErrMsg}<span class=\"ajax_close\"></span></p>";
        if ($ErrDie):
            die;
        endif;
    }

    //PHPErro :: personaliza o gatilho do PHP
    function PHPErro($ErrNo, $ErrMsg, $ErrFile, $ErrLine) {
        $CssClass = ($ErrNo == E_USER_NOTICE ? WS_INFOR : ($ErrNo == E_USER_WARNING ? WS_ALERT  :  ($ErrNo == E_USER_ERROR ? WS_ERROR : $ErrNo)));
        echo "<p class=\"trigger {$CssClass}\">";
        echo "<b>Erro na linha: {$ErrLine} :: </b> {$ErrMsg} <br>";
        echo "<small>{$ErrFile}</small>";
        echo "<span class=\"ajax_close\"></span></p>";

        if($ErrNo == E_USER_ERROR):
            die;
        endif;
}
//error_reporting(0);
//ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );
//set_error_handler('PHPerro');



$getUrl = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_DEFAULT)));
$setUrl = (empty($getUrl) ? 'index' : $getUrl);
$Url = explode('/', $setUrl);

$pg_name = 'Youtuber divulga - Vamos divulgar';
$pg_site = 'Youtube Divulga';
$pg_google_author = '';
$pg_google_publisher = '';
$pg_fb_app = '';
$pg_fb_author = 'Guilhrem de sousa';
$pg_fb_page = '';
$pg_twitter = '';
$pg_domain = '';
$pg_sitekit = INCLUDE_PATH . '/img/sitekit/';

switch ($Url[0]):
    case 'index':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

    case 'controler':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = 'swith/controler.php';
        break;

     case 'videos':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

    case 'youtubers':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

    case 'viwer':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

case 'sobre':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

case 'mychannel':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

case 'myvideos':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;
case 'config':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

case 'newvideo':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;



case 'sair':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

case 'follows':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

case 'user':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;

    case 'teste':
        $pg_title = $pg_name;
        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME;
        break;


//case 'admin':
//        $pg_title = $pg_name;
//        $pg_desc = 'Conheça o curso que vai te ensinar o método HTML5 do Jeito Certo. Aprenda a Desenvolver, Otimizar, Distribuir e Lançar Sites Na Internet!';
//        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . 'index.jpg';
//        $pg_url = HOME;
//        break;


    default :
        $pg_title = 'Desculpe, não encontrado o conteúdo relacionado.';
        $pg_desc = 'Você está vendo agora a página 404 pois não encontramos conteúdo relacionado à <b>' . $setUrl . '</b>, mas não saia ainda. Temos algumas dicas para te ajudar com sua pesquisa!';
        $pg_image = $pg_sitekit . '404.jpg';
        $pg_url = HOME . '/404';
        break;
endswitch;
```

.htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

controler.php

```
<?php

echo "teste";
```

Este erro ocorre quando clico no botão para mandar a requesição vem com o codigo fonte html de uma pagina 404

Comment: A URL funciona se digitada diretamente no browser?

Comment: Não seria só `switch` ou `switch/controller` ?

Comment: @mauhumor não funciona testei agora para ver

Comment: @lvcs não funcionou por causa que ele esta em sub pastas e não esta especificado no config.inc posso tentar fazer com que ele leia isso vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver o problema estava no caminho e não na url amigável tive de por todo o caminho deis da raiz do site até o local do arquivo e parou de dar o erro obrigado a todos que ajudaram